# ReactiveCommand никогда нельзя выполнить

Tags: c#, wpf, reactive

Начал осваивать MVVM и фреймворк ReactiveUI, но остановился на создании команды.
У меня во вьюмодели есть ReactiveCommand, которая по выполнению должна возвращать пользователя с введенными email и паролем. Но по какой-то причине CanExecute этой команды всегда false (проверял и с IObservable, и без - результат один, кнопка не нажимается).

```
public class AuthorizationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _email;
    private string _password;

    public AuthorizationViewModel()
    {
        var canExecute = this.WhenAnyValue(
            x => x.Email, x => x.Password,
            (email, password) =>
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password));

        Authorize = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => AccountingService.SearchUser(Email, Password));
        // тоже самое, что и
        // Authorize = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => AccountingService.SearchUser(Email, Password), canExecute);
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _email, value);
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _password, value);
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, User?> Authorize { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в отсутствии привязки вью к вьюмодели. Добавление дата контекста решило проблему:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:AuthorizationViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```